# correct psilocybin molecular structure

Tags: molecular-structure

I'm writing a research paper on psilocybin.  I need to know the correct chemical structure.  When I look online it it shows different ones.  There is one with two OH molecules attached to the phosphorous and there is one with one OH and one O- attached to the phosphorous.  There is also one that I found with a O+ attached to the phosphorous.  Are they all they same or are they interchangeable?  Are there different ones?  I can't find a clear answer.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, it cannot be an $\ce{O+}$, as that would require a triple bond to the oxygen, making the phosphorus in the middle quite unhappy.

Of the other two alternatives, both are correct -- however, it matters what environment you're considering the molecule. In neutral or slightly basic conditions, it will be an $\ce{O-},$ while in slightly acidic conditions, it will be an $\ce{OH}.$

Let me know if you need any clarification on why this is the case -- I have no idea what your level of knowledge is.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. My knowledge is fairly low.  Can you tell me which it would be in it's natural form?  Why would they differ due to ph?

Comment: Since this is a natural product (found in mushrooms), most likely it is found primarily inside of cells, which have a close to neutral pH. Thus, it is likely found in its deprotonated form (the one with the $\ce{O-}$). The reason that pH matters is because the difference between $\ce{OH}$ and $\ce{O-}$ is a measly little $\ce{H+}$ (notice that regular hydrogen has one proton and one electron, so $\ce{H+}$ has lost its electron, and is simply a proton - hence the word de- _proton_ -ated). pH is just a fancy way of measuring the amount of $\ce{H+}$ found in a solution, so that's why pH matters.

Comment: This answer completely neglects, that it is a zwitterion, and that both structures will be present at all times. The degree of protonation/deprotonation is of course pH dependent. Resonance of the phosphate group is also important.

Comment: I know this... but I suspect that the original question was asked with no intention of understanding the actual chemistry regarding the phosphate group, but rather to find the correct structure to put into a report of some sort. While the degree of protonation on both the phosphate and the amino varies, the "most natural" form is indeed the zwitterion. Of course, there will be 4 different structures in equilibrium with each other (ignoring the second deprotonation of the phosphate), but the one most prevalent at physiological pH is the zwitterion.

Comment: pH and pKa are the measure of the amount of dissociation, or H+ ions.  At pH7, there are 0.0000001 H+ ions for each molecule of H2O. The pKa of water is 14; at pH 14 half of the water will be deprotonated. The pKa of psilicybin is around 6.5; at pH 6.5 half of the psilocybin will be dissociated (O-). In neutral conditions (pH7) the amount of dissociated (O-) psilocybin will  be higher than the "associated" (OH) psilocybin. Cytosolic pH of fungal cells is about 6.95. At pH 8, roughly 90% of psilocybin will be in the O- form. At ph 10.4 ~50% of the dimethylamine nitrogen will be deprotonated.